# td stack when using responsive classes

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am working on table which hide some `td` , it work if I target with `:nth-child()` but when I use class `.hidden-xs` it stack the table on top on each other.

```css
.hidden-xs {
  background: red;
  display: none;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .hidden-xs {
    display: block;
    background: grey;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="hidden-xs">First Name</th>
    <th class="hidden-xs">Last Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Nationality</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Hotel</th>
    <th>Checked In</th>
    <th>Comments</th>
    <th>Boolean</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="hidden-xs">Nofel</td>
    <td class="hidden-xs">Khan</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>American</td>
    <td>Flying</td>
    <td>Holiday Inn</td>
    <td>No</td>
    <td>This is new stuff</td>
    <td>No</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I do not understand this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're setting the display to `block` on large screens instead of what it should be for a table cell, `table-cell`:

```css
.hidden-xs {
  background: red;
  display: none;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .hidden-xs {
    display: table-cell;
    background: grey;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="hidden-xs">First Name</th>
    <th class="hidden-xs">Last Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Nationality</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Hotel</th>
    <th>Checked In</th>
    <th>Comments</th>
    <th>Boolean</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="hidden-xs">Nofel</td>
    <td class="hidden-xs">Khan</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>American</td>
    <td>Flying</td>
    <td>Holiday Inn</td>
    <td>No</td>
    <td>This is new stuff</td>
    <td>No</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: what is the difference,I never heard that one?

Comment: @Nofel See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display and https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#valdef-display-table-cell

Answer (score 0):

For table, you should use `display: table-cell`. Another way to do it is to set it to `display: none` when under 992px screen size:

> @media screen and (max-width: 992px) { .hidden-xs{   display:none; background:red;   } }